# How to update only two colums in database from csv without touching data in other columns using python and sqlite3?

Tags: database, csv, sqlite, python-3.6

hi I have a database which looks like this image [image]

I have a csv which has two columns City and Main_city. I want to update Main_City against the City column from csv into database but without damaging other data into the database. How can i do this?

I do not know the logic behind it.

below are my codes:

```
import csv

data_obj = {}
def readfiles():
    f = open("city.csv", "r")
    data = f.read()
    lst = data.split("\n")
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        val = lst[i].split(",")
        data_obj[val[0]] = val[1]
        #print(data_obj[val[0]])
    print(data_obj)
readfiles()

conn = sqlite3.connect('99_data_increment.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crawled (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, State , XID , Project_Name , City , Main_City , Registration_Number , Promoter_Name , Rera_URL , PDF_text, Crawled_Date , Status, Names, Transaction_Date, Comments, Call_Contact_Number, Creation_Type, Builder_Website)")
New_project_db.insert(statess, XID, Projectname, City, maincity, Registration_number, promotername, rera_url, blank, fdate, "CREATED", agents_names, fdate, blank, blank, blank, blank)
## didn't getting logic behind
```

My csv looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import your CSV file with the updates into a temporary table, it's really easy to do. I want to say that pandas makes this import trivial in Python, but I'm not familiar enough to say for sure. At the very least actually using the csv library you're importing but not using would help.

Anyways, here's a way to do it from the sqlite3 shell, which is handy for a one-off update, but not good if you're trying to automate it for repeated use. Should be easy enough to adapt to python though, as the `UPDATE` is the important part once you've got the new data loaded into the database.

```
$ sqlite3 99_data_increment.db
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import updates.csv new_cities
sqlite> CREATE INDEX new_cities_idx ON new_cities(City);
sqlite> UPDATE crawled AS c
         SET Main_City =
            (SELECT "Main City" FROM new_cities AS n WHERE c.City = n.City)
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM new_cities AS n WHERE c.City = n.City);
sqlite> DROP TABLE new_cities;
sqlite> .quit
```

Comment: Actually i used your update command , i had almost slipped that out. Thank you for your help. It is great learning here